# Rails 4 query unique by single attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, arel

So this is more of an arel question than anything but here's what I am trying to do.

I have three objects lets say, called Items

```
<Item id: 1, name: 'Book'>
<Item id: 2, name: 'Car'>
<Item id: 3, name: 'Book'>
```

I want to do a query that will just return only one of each unique "name" attributes.

Something like `Item.select('distinct(name), items.*')`

This doesn't work though, it still returns all three items.

How can I form this query so that it only returns:

```
<Item id: 1, name: 'Book'>
<Item id: 2, name: 'Car'>
```

Comment: so which book object should it return, 1 or 3?

Comment: @sevenseacat doesn't matter, either works.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to get the entire model back, but still maintain uniqueness, you can use this:

```
Item.select('distinct on (name) *')
```

I've only tested this with a Postgres database. It may or may not work with mysql.

Comment: the answer above will return all column, if you want select only some column you can try with `Item.select('distinct on (name) name, id')`

Comment: This is brilliant! I have been looking for this everywhere :-)

Comment: I've been freaking out because I realised I needed to grab only the most recent records on a DB, and I was due to show something to my boss but for the life of me couldn't get it to work until I found this. You are a life saver, that you!!!

Comment: Anyone knows how can I achieve this with mysql?

Comment: In mysql: `SELECT distinct on (name) * FROM items`

Comment: For Mysql see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47528353/5615038)

Answer (score 11):

Please try this:

```
Item.select('distinct name')
```

Comment: That kind of works. It returns the objects with just the 'name' attribute. I want to return the whole object. I get this: <Item id: nil, name: 'Book'>, <Item id: nil, name: 'Car'>

Comment: Try Item.select('id', 'name')

Comment: @goddamnyouryan It's a bit late, but see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

If you only need an array with the names, without the ID, you can do:

```
Item.pluck(:name).uniq
```

SQL query result:

```
#=> SELECT `items`.`name` FROM `items`
```

** edit **

The `uniq` is ran on the array of records. Be careful if you expect a lot of records.
SQL Distinct is much faster.

If so, use vee's answer above, with a `map`:

`Item.select('distinct name').map(:name)`

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment on posts yet, so, putting this as another answer for the question.

In case of someone still searches for this, [@BananaNeil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30565093/6194829) is correct. However, putting `distinct` in `select` didn't work for me (Rails 5.2.2). Separating these two did fix my problem.

```rb
klass.where(
  # Your query or whatever
).distinct.select('on (attribute) *')
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4 try `Items.all.to_a.uniq { |item| item.name }`

In Rails 3 you should be able to just do `Items.uniq_by { |item| item.name }`

When you call `uniq` on an array, you can pass it a block to dictate how to determine uniqueness. In Rails 3 you used to be able to use `uniq_by`, but it became deprecated in Rails 4. So one method I found is to just convert the ActiveRecord Relation to an array and call `uniq` on that.

Comment: This is great for small queries, but terrible performance for large datasets.

Comment: Really poor idea to `.to_a` a query which loads the data into memory.

Answer (score 0):

For Mysql, your can use `group` with  [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) disabled,

```
Item.group(:name).to_sql
=> "SELECT `items`.* FROM `items`  GROUP BY name"
```

See [Is there ANY_VALUE capability for mysql 5.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089347/is-there-any-value-capability-for-mysql-5-6)