# Weird Group/sort behavior in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am not DB guy and I could not get why this simple case work perfectly on 5.6 but fail on 5.7 the weird way.

Use case: get the list of TOP-rated comic along with  some info like title, author...

As long as I select only non-text colunm , then it sort correctly

```
            SELECT c.id, c.title IF(AVG(r.score) IS NOT NULL, AVG(r.score), 0) as `rateScore`,  COUNT(r.`entityId`) as `rateCount`  
        FROM `manga_comic` as c
        LEFT JOIN `base_rate` as r
        ON( r.`entityType` = 'comic' AND c.id = r.`entityId` )


        GROUP BY c.`id`
        ORDER BY `rateScore` DESC, rateCount DESC
```

Adding a text column like "c.description" will ignore rateScore while value rateCount.

Again, only 5.7 for me  (or maybe some configuration which mess things up). I hope not to recode alot of screen just because of upgrading to mysql 5.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there ANY\_VALUE capability for mysql 5.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089347/is-there-any-value-capability-for-mysql-5-6)

Comment: Is the text column being added included in both the select and group by?

Comment: @e4c5 : that's some "seriously" quick reply, it looks promising, thanks

Comment: I don't see how adding `c.description` (to the select clause I assume) could have any effect on `group by` or `order by`. It doesn't even have to be added to `group by`, because it is functionally dependent on `c.id`. Can you please elaborate what exactly is different? (I don't understad your explanation "will ignore rateScore while value rateCount".) Can you post the altered query that is causing the problems?

Comment: This would result in a syntax error

Comment: @Strawberry: Are you referring to my comment? `c.description` should be functionally dependent on `c.id`. So it suffices to have `c.id` in `group by` in current standard SQL. As long as `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is not set, MySQL should be able to run the statement with `c.description` added to the select clause without problems.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner No. I'm not referring to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I got it works. Thanks to the hint from the answer of [Is there ANY_VALUE capability for mysql 5.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089347/is-there-any-value-capability-for-mysql-5-6)

```
        SELECT DISTINCT c.id,
    c.author,
    c.title,
    ....... ,

    r.avgScore as `rateScore`,  r.`rateCount` ,

    f.id as mediaId , f.type as mediaType, f.data as cover

                FROM `manga_comic` as c
                LEFT JOIN (
                Select entityId,   AVG(r0.score) as `avgScore`,  COUNT(r0.`entityId`) as `rateCount` 
                FROM `base_rate` as r0

                Where  r0.`entityType` = 'comic'
                    GROUP BY r0.`entityType`  , r0.`entityId`
                ) r
                ON(  c.id = r.`entityId` )



                LEFT JOIN entity e on ( `c`.`id` = `e`.`entityId` and e.entityType='comic' and plugin='manga' )
                LEFT JOIN media_file f on ( `e`.`id` = `f`.`entityId` and f.type='cover')
                WHERE 1 


                ORDER BY `rateScore` DESC , rateCount DESC
                LIMIT 0, 20
```

Thank you  e4c5 for the link and others for your time and support.

Conclusion: so far I had so many trouble from mysql 5.7 so think twice before upgrading your PROD to 5.7