# SQL ORDER BY clause causing GROUP BY/aggregate error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I get this error:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "relationships.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

from this query:

```
last_check = @user.last_check.to_i
@new_relationships = User.select('*')
                         .from("(#{@rels_unordered.to_sql}) AS rels_unordered")
                         .joins("
                    INNER JOIN  relationships
                    ON          rels_unordered.id = relationships.character_id
                    WHERE       EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM relationships.created_at) > #{last_check}
                    ORDER BY    relationships.created_at DESC
                    ")
```

Without the ORDER BY line, it works fine. I don't understand what the GROUP BY clause is. How do I get it working and still order by relationships.created_at?

EDIT

I understand you can `GROUP BY relationships.created_at`. But isn't grouping unnecessary? Is the problem that `relationship.created_at` is not included in the `SELECT`? How do you include it? If you've already done an `INNER JOIN` with `relationships`, why the hell isn't `relationships.created_at` included in the result??

I've just realised this is all happening because the logs show the query begins with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM....`. So the COUNT is the aggregate function. But I never requested a COUNT! Why does the query start with that?

EDIT 2

Ok, this seems to be happening because of lazy querying. The first thing that happens to @new_relationships is `@new_relationships.any?` This affects the query and turns it into a count. So I suppose the question is, how do I force the query to run as originally intended? And also to check if @new_relationships is empty without affecting the sql query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there ANY\_VALUE capability for mysql 5.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089347/is-there-any-value-capability-for-mysql-5-6)

Comment: When GROUP BY (and SELECT DISTINCT and UNION), only select list items may be specified in the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add group by along with your order by clause

```
last_check = @user.last_check.to_i     
@new_relationships = 
  User.select('"rels_unordered".*')
      .from("(#{@rels_unordered.to_sql}) AS rels_unordered")
      .joins("INNER JOIN relationships   
              ON rels_unordered.id = relationships.character_id 
              WHERE EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM relationships.created_at) > #{last_check} 
              GROUP BY relationships.created_at
              ORDER BY relationships.created_at DESC ")
```

Comment: Sorry to un-accept your answer, but: the change you suggested worked initially, but it is now complaining that `rels_unordered.id must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. Would it be better to avoid a `GROUP BY` clause altogether, and instead include `relationships.created_at` in the aggregate function? How would that be coded?

Answer (score 0):

It's asking for a `GROUP BY` after your `FROM` clause in your `EXTRACT` (essentially a subselect). There's ways around it, but I've found it's often easier to make a `GROUP BY` work. Try: ...`FROM relationships.created_at GROUP BY id` or whatever indexing column you are using from that table. It seems like your `ORDER BY` is conflicting with itself. By grouping the subselect data it should lose its conflict.

Comment: NB: While it should lose the conflict it can also eliminate desired data from your output, if that happens sample tables would help get you the right syntax