# sql avg comparison not behaving as expected

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, having

I am trying to filter out all positive averages by using the line

```
 HAVING AVG(blurt_analysis.sentiment) < 0
```

however for an unexpected reason this line isn't doing as expected and in fact is making my query return nothing and im having a hard time figuring out why my query looks like

```
SELECT topic.id,topic.description,blurt.location,count(blurt.blurtid)as 'number of blurts',AVG(blurt_analysis.sentiment) as avgSentiment
FROM topic, blurt_analysis,blurt
WHERE topic.id=blurt_analysis.topicid AND blurt.blurtid = blurt_analysis.blurtid AND blurt.email = blurt_analysis.email 
group by blurt.location,topic.id
HAVING AVG(blurt_analysis.sentiment) < 0
```

the return looks like this without the having line and is empty with the line

```
1   shoes   California  2   2.5000
2   speaker California  3   1.3333
3   bats    California  3   1.0000
4   hoodies California  2   -0.5000
5   caps    California  1   -2.0000
6   pens    California  2   0.0000
7   games   California  4   1.2500
1   shoes   Colarado    1   1.0000
2   speaker Colarado    3   1.6667
3   bats    Colarado    1   1.0000
5   caps    Colarado    1   3.0000
7   games   Colarado    1   1.0000
```

with the first column being topicid the second being topic description the third being blurt location the 4th being the number of blurts and the 5th being avg sentiment(what im trying to filter positive numbers from)

UPDATE I still have not managed to figure out why the query doesnt work with having but I managed to filter positive numbers with another add making my sql look like

```
SELECT topic.id,topic.description,blurt.location,count(blurt.blurtid)as 'number of blurts',AVG(blurt_analysis.sentiment) as avgSentiment
FROM topic, blurt_analysis,blurt
WHERE topic.id=blurt_analysis.topicid AND blurt.blurtid = blurt_analysis.blurtid AND blurt.email = blurt_analysis.email AND blurt_analysis.sentiment <0
group by blurt.location,topic.id,topic.description
```

Comment: Could you please rewrite your query using `JOIN` syntax? Unlikely that it will solve your problem, but we might better anderstand, what's going on in your query.

Comment: I can try but I'm new to SQL and have not actually written a query with join before

Comment: And best would be if you create small sample data, that can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there ANY\_VALUE capability for mysql 5.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089347/is-there-any-value-capability-for-mysql-5-6)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with NVL or CASE to replace null values? It worked for me one time.

i.e.: `AVG(NVL(blurt_analysis.sentiment,0))`

Comment: trying HAVING AVG(NVL(blurt_analysis.sentiment,0)) < 0;  gave me an error VNL doesn't exsist

Answer (score 0):

You were lucky; now you're unlucky.  each non-aggregate column in the `select` clause must appear in `group by`.  A quick glance shows `topic.description` is among the missing.

Apparently MySQL tolerated your original query, but fell over when you added HAVING.  Or you're getting nondeterministic results; I don't know.  But I bet if you correct your query, your HAVING clause will behave better.  :-)

Comment: I added that to the group by making it group by blurt.location,topic.id,topic.description and that did not change the behavior of my HAVING

Comment: `topic.description` is probably functionaly dependent on `topic.id`. Thus the result set is well defined.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel meaning it doesn't need to be included after all? including it or leaving it off has had no change at all to the query or the broken HAVING line

Comment: @AlexChapp If `topic.id` is primary key, then adding `topic.description` to the group by clause should not change the result. However MySQL might complain depending on SQL mode. But it doesn't in your case.

Comment: Thanks it is indeed primary