# October CMS - SQL request incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, group-by, octobercms, mysql-error-1055

i have a strange issue in my local environment :
wamp64
mysql 5.7.14
OctoberCMS 382

this encountered in several plugins, For example, this one that attempts to display a list of slides in the backend

> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY
>   clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
>   'dbname.flosch_slideshow_slides.sort_order' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;
>
> this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
>
> (SQL:
>
> select `flosch_slideshow_slides`.`slideshow_id`, count(*) as count
>
> from `flosch_slideshow_slides`
>
> where `flosch_slideshow_slides`.`slideshow_id` in (2, 1)
>
> group by `flosch_slideshow_slides`.`slideshow_id`
>
> order by `sort_order` asc
>
> )

other example slightly different. this one that attempts to display a list of products on the frontend

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #51
>   of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
>   column 'dbname.jiri_jkshop_products_categories.category_id'
>   which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;
>
> this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
>
> (SQL:
>
> select * from `jiri_jkshop_products` inner join
>   `jiri_jkshop_products_categories` on `id` =
>   `jiri_jkshop_products_categories`.`product_id` where `active` = 1 and
>   `category_id` in (8) and `visibility` = 1 group by `id` order by
>   `title` asc
>
> )

Those requests are triggered here :

Backend\Behaviors\ListController->listRender()

so i don't have the hand on it

I specify that it works perfectly in the remote server and in the local environment of my mate

Another interesting point is that since I applied the latest updates for the system (from version 365 to 382) and all the plugins installed. Then, to test, I did the same on the remote server and it still works

As i work mainly locally, this is very very annoying

have you some ideas to fix it ? ideally without modify mysql/sql_mode

thanks & regards,
Patrick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there ANY\_VALUE capability for mysql 5.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089347/is-there-any-value-capability-for-mysql-5-6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a long time now, MySQL has contained a notorious nonstandard extension to `GROUP BY`, which allows oddball behavior in the name of efficiency. This extension has allowed countless developers around the world to use `GROUP BY` in production code without understanding what they were doing.

In particular, it's foolish to use `SELECT *` in a `GROUP BY` query, because a standard `GROUP BY` clause requires enumerating the columns. Many developers have been foolish this way.

Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

The MySQL team has been trying to fix this misfeature without messing up production code. They added a `sql_mode` flag in 5.7.5 named [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) to compel standard behavior.  In a recent release, they turned on that flag by default. When you upgraded your local MySQL to 5.7.14, the flag got switched on and your production code, dependent on the old extension, stopped working.

Your choices?

1. fix the offending SQL queries, or get the plugin authors to do that.
2. roll back to a version of MySQL compatible out-of-the-box with the application software you use.
3. change your server's [`sql_mode`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) to get rid of the newly set `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode.

You can change the mode by doing a `SET` command.

```
SET  sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

should do the trick if you do it right after your application connects to MySQL.

Or, you can find [the init file in your MySQL installation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html), locate the `sql_mode=` line, and change it to omit `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, and restart your server.

That first offending query? add `sort_order` to the `GROUP BY` clause, like this.

```
select flosch_slideshow_slides.slideshow_id, count(*) as count
  from flosch_slideshow_slides
 where flosch_slideshow_slides.slideshow_id in (2, 1)
 group by flosch_slideshow_slides.slideshow_id, sort_order
 order by sort_order asc
```

Will this break anything? Probably not.

Your second offending query?  It contains `SELECT *`, so you will have to unravel the code surrounding the query to find out which columns are actually used before you can fix the `GROUP BY` clause. If this is a plugin, that job would best be done by its authors.

Comment: thanks Mister Jones, thanks a lot, awesome reply, so i notify plugin's authors and i try to fix involved queries.