# incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

So while upgrading a project from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.2, somehow this query in one of my models which looks like:

```
rows = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("Select q.id,q.times_taken,avg(qr.correct)*100,q.difficulty,q.weight,sk.name,sa.name,sub.name,q.tag_list from 
  (select qu.id,qu.times_taken,qu.difficulty,qu.weight,group_concat(tags.name) tag_list,qu.subject_id,qu.subject_area_id
    from questions qu left join taggings t on (qu.id = taggable_id) left join tags on (t.tag_id = tags.id) 
    where qu.id in (#{@questions_out_ids.join(',')}) and t.taggable_type='Question' group by t.taggable_id) q
  left join subjects sub on (q.subject_id = sub.id) left join subject_areas sa on (q.subject_area_id = sa.id) 
  left join skills_subject_areas ssa on (sa.id = ssa.subject_area_id) left join skills sk on (ssa.skill_id = sk.id), 
  archived_question_results qr,attempts a where  qr.question_id = q.id and a.id = qr.attempt_id and a.is_normalized = 1 
  and a.state = 'complete' group by qr.question_id order by q.id")
```

has started producing a mysql error as under:

```
ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #6 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'faces_development.sk.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

I've looked at other answers of the similar questions, and I know I need to include a certain table's `id` column too in the `GROUP BY` clause but since my query is extremely complex, the options I've tried haven't been of much use. I am using gem `mysql2 0.3.0` Suggestions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there ANY\_VALUE capability for mysql 5.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089347/is-there-any-value-capability-for-mysql-5-6)

Comment: No, this one is related to rails. They are related but not duplicated.

Answer (score 33):

`config/database.yml`:

```
development: # Or test, or production, or all of them.
  ...
  variables:
    sql_mode: TRADITIONAL
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!!

Comment: This seems to apply the rule whenever you reboot the app - it doesn't need you to recreate or migrate the DB or anything, which is nice.

Comment: Hint: Suddenly we startet to get those exception again, even though we set the sql_mode like above. BUT apt unattended-upgrades made an automatic security update of MySQL and that seem to have reset the server default back again to only_full. In our case **restarting the app** reapplied the variables setting and it worked again.

Answer (score 6):

in your `config/database.yml` file:

```
default: &default
  variables:
    sql_mode: TRADITIONAL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution to my issue, apparently it was the `6th` expression in outer `select`, i.e `sk.name` which was producing problems. Adding the same expression to the outer `group by` clause fixed it for me.

```
rows = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select q.id,q.times_taken,avg(qr.correct)*100,q.difficulty,q.weight,sk.name,sa.name,sub.name,q.tag_list from 
  (select qu.id,qu.times_taken,qu.difficulty,qu.weight,group_concat(tags.name) tag_list,qu.subject_id,qu.subject_area_id
    from questions qu left join taggings t on (qu.id = taggable_id) left join tags on (t.tag_id = tags.id) 
    where qu.id in (#{@questions_out_ids.join(',')}) and t.taggable_type='Question' group by t.taggable_id) q
  left join subjects sub on (q.subject_id = sub.id) left join subject_areas sa on (q.subject_area_id = sa.id) 
  left join skills_subject_areas ssa on (sa.id = ssa.subject_area_id) left join skills sk on (ssa.skill_id = sk.id), 
  archived_question_results qr,attempts a where  qr.question_id = q.id and a.id = qr.attempt_id and a.is_normalized = 1 
  and a.state = 'complete' group by sk.name, qr.question_id order by q.id")
```