# Non Group by column in select working in one machine and not in another

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-error-1055

I have two machines and I am trying to run the below-mentioned query in both of them.

```
SELECT 
    bdm.brand_id AS brandId,
    bdm.brand_name AS brandName,
    fse.seller_code AS dummySeller,
    bdm.feed_source AS feedSource
FROM
    `brand_distributor_mapping` bdm
        JOIN
    `feed_source` fse ON bdm.feed_source = fse.name
GROUP BY bdm.brand_id ,bdm.feed_source;
```

It's working on one machine and giving Error code 1055 in another.

Mysql version of both machine:

1. Not working - mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.19, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper.
2. Working - mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.53, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Comment: The columns `brand_name` and `seller_code` either need to be in an aggregate function, or you could use a subquery to determine values for them.

Comment: Please update your question with sample data and expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there ANY\_VALUE capability for mysql 5.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089347/is-there-any-value-capability-for-mysql-5-6)

Comment: As mentioned by Ravinder Reddy, it is because of SQL_MODE=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. 
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be due to `SQL_MODE` set to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` by `default`.

Better you always practice a full group by aggregation in your queries. Otherwise though MySQL accepts and retrieves results based on the `SQL_MODE` set, they may not be correct.

You may want to change your group by clause like below:

```
GROUP BY
    bdm.brand_id,
    bdm.brand_name,
    fse.seller_code,
    bdm.feed_source
```

Refer to: [**MySQL Documentation on `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

Comment: That must be it.  
I'll try to fetch data using inner query. 
Thanks.