# Join Multiple Sql statements from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, pivot, relational-database

I have read many post on this topic but I am not yet satisfied.

I have a table called `ticket` with the following columns

```
TicketID | AirlineID | PassengerID | TicketPrice | TicketVolume | DestinationCountry | ExitCountry | TicketDate`
```

I have multiple queries like

```
SELECT AVG(TicketPrice) 
FROM ticket 
WHERE TicketPrice between 552 and 1302
AND AirlineID=1 
AND TicketDate between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31' 
GROUP BY TicketDate

SELECT AVG(TicketPrice) 
FROM ticket 
WHERE TicketPrice between 552 and 1302 
AND AirlineID=1 
AND TicketDate between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31' 
GROUP BY TicketDate
```

Please how can I join both queries to form another table side by side

```
+--------------------------------++-----------
| AirlineID || Average Ticket Price 2016/2017|
+--------------------------------++-----------
```

they are actually more queries.

Comment: Can you give the expected result with sample data?

Comment: This makes no sense so far. You select AirlineID=1. And in your results you have a column AirlineID. Of course it will only contein ones. Then you group by TicketDate, so as to get one row per ticket date. But your result doesn>'t contain a column TicketDate, so you'll get many rows, not knowing what date refer to. Please clarify.

Comment: "they are actually more queries". Aha. What are these queries like? Same, but different year? What is the result to look like then? One column per year? Do you know beforehand which years or shall these depend on the current date or the years existing in the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `CASE` to achieve this:

Try this:

```
SELECT
    AirlineID,
    AVG(CASE WHEN TicketDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31' THEN TicketPrice END),
    AVG(CASE WHEN TicketDate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' THEN TicketPrice END) 
FROM ticket 
WHERE
    TicketPrice BETWEEN 552 AND 1302 AND
    AirlineID = 1 
GROUP BY
    AirlineID, TicketDate;
```

Comment: Thanks @DineshDB but I also was to return the AirlineID as a column because I have up to 6 AirlineIDs. When I tried your query, it returned only the case columns

Comment: I tried it and added the between AirlineIDs to obtain my result.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution for this, maybe not the desired output by OP but in my opinion a better output and also no need for hardcoded dates

```
SELECT AirlineID, extract(YEAR from TicketDate) as year, AVG(TicketPrice)
FROM ticket
WHERE TicketPrice between 552 and 1302
GROUP BY AirLineID, year
```

Comment: Complained of the group clause

Comment: Not for me on MariaDb, what database did you try on? Maybe change year to something else if it is a problem with that word, like avg_year.

Comment: Per year you are selecting the avarage ticket price and an arbitrarily picked airline ID. Depending on settings MySQL may allow this or not. You may have to use `ANY_VALUE(AirlineID)` to achieve that. But then: Is this really your intention or have you made a mistake in your query? Maybe you want AirlineID in the `GROUP BY` clause instead.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, yes I had forgotten airlineid in my group by. Thank you.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, is it [this setting discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089347/is-there-any-value-capability-for-mysql-5-6) you are referring to?

Comment: Yes, AirlineID is not functionally dependent on year and must hence be either in the `GROUP BY` clause or get aggregated (via `ANY_VALUE`). The `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode ensures that you obey this.

Comment: @DestinyAlabi, group by should work now with my latest update

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merge the results into a single table, use UNION.

```
SELECT {...}
UNION
SELECT {...}
```

The SELECT statements must return the same columns

Comment: This would give the two averages as separate _rows_, not columns.

Comment: WhenI tried this, it put everything tor the same column

Answer (score 0):

***SQL***

```
 SELECT 
 (SELECT AVG(TicketPrice) FROM ticket 
    WHERE TicketPrice between 552 and 1302
    AND AirlineID=1 
    AND TicketDate between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31' 
    GROUP BY TicketDate) as Col1,
(SELECT AVG(TicketPrice) FROM ticket 
    WHERE TicketPrice between 552 and 1302 
    AND AirlineID=1 
    AND TicketDate between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31' 
    GROUP BY TicketDate) as Col2
```

Comment: ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row