# SQL joining different rows into one row and changing the output based on the values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'd like to output two rows into one and change the output based on the values

SQL syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM course 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN located ON course.course_id = located.course_id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN city ON city.city_id = located.city_id
```

PHP syntax:

```
  while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
          <div class="card bg-black" style="text-align: center;">
               <div class="card-body">
                   <h3 class="card-text text-white"><?= $row['name']?></h3>
                   <p class="text-danger"><?= $row['city_name'];?></p>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
   <?php
   }
   ?>
```

The output:

[image]

How I'd like it to be:

[image]

But if it is only one city it would show the name of the city which happened to be "City 1" or "City 2".

Comment: Are you looking for `COUNT(*)` in SQL?

Comment: sounds like a count of cities grouped by course, probably.

Comment: Not exactly I forgot to mention I'll edit it right away, that if its only one city it would show the name of the city which happened to be "City 1" or "City 2"

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using PDO? With PDO you have really cool fetch modes that would definitely help you achieve what you want.

Comment: You could also do something like this in SQL `IF(COUNT(*) > 1, COUNT(*), Name) as cityname` Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: The reason is that I never knew about that. I'm a beginner so would love to get some directions or advice on where to start learning about it.

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: I'll try IF(COUNT(*) > 1, COUNT(*), Name) as cityname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by grouping the results in SQL and then using a conditional select. For example:

```
SELECT 
  course.name, 
  IF(COUNT(*) > 1, COUNT(*), MIN(city_name)) as city_name
FROM course 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN located ON course.course_id = located.course_id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN city ON city.city_id = located.city_id
GROUP BY course.course_id
```

In your case, maybe something like this would be more suitable

```
SELECT 
  IF(city_count > 1, CONCAT(city_count, ' cities'), city_name) as city_name
FROM course 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT course_id, COUNT(*) as city_count, MIN(city_name) as city_name
      FROM located  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN city ON city.city_id = located.city_id
      GROUP BY located.course_id
    ) cities ON course.course_id = cities.course_id
GROUP BY course.course_id
```

Comment: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'nkursdb.city.city_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: @Nomi You can ignore it with [`ANY_VALUE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value)

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089347/is-there-any-value-capability-for-mysql-5-6

Comment: Nope I can't get it working

Comment: can u edit your demonstration with the ANY_VALUE() part

Comment: @Nomi `ANY_VALUE()` won't work if you are using MariaDB. If you Google that error message you can learn more about it.

Comment: It works but there one problem with it is how I'm going to get the data from the course table

Comment: @Nomi I don't know your full database schema, so I am only guessing. However, I only wanted to provide an idea of how to solve an issue like this, and I wasn't planning on implementing the full SQL query for you. I hope that my suggestion has given you an idea on how to proceed, but it is your task now to complete it.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help